Is there a connection between Kaprekar’s constant ($6174$) and the golden ratio?
Kaprekar’s constant is $6174$, and the golden ratio translated into percentages is $61.80\%$. Pretty close. Is this explainable or just coincident?

The golden ratio is about $1.618$. How is it that “translated into percentages is $61.80%$”?

@JoséCarlosSantos It's probably the inverse $1/\varphi = 0.618\dots$

Are we gonna land in a new unsolved problem/ unproven conjecture or something?

@Spectre I hope so!

@JoséCarlosSantos I mean the square in a golden rectangle.

@RichardB the area each big square in a golden rectangle of sides $F_n$ and $F_{n-1}$ occupy, you mean?

That's the same thing as @Keplerto suggested. But how were we supposed to have guessed it?

@JoséCarlosSantos is it the same as what I said?

@RichardB idk what to call it, but maybe examine what both the constants stand for and deduce some similarity (and a really striking one too, if they ever can be deduced to have some relation) in the processes that resulted in them.

Yeah well, I’m not very good at math. I was just wondering if anyone knew if there was a connection, Kaprekar’s constant and the rules I follow when (graphically) designing stuff seemed close but also equally magical.

@Spectre My comment was about the sentence “I mean the square in a golden rectangle.”

If there is a connection, it probably does not depend on the base $10,$ so one way to check would be to compare Krapekar constants in different bases to the golden ratio. If no further similarities are found, then it's likely a coincidence.
